# Cannot send data to create new product in database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to create PHP file for uploading data to create new product in database, but it has to be unique file for every database with the same structure.

Code edited by me looks like this (I don't know anything about PHP, I'm just trying to use codes from web to make app work with database) :

```
<?php
    $response = array();
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['review']) && isset($_POST['rating']) && isset($_POST['database_name'])) {

        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $review = $_POST['review'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $database_name = $_POST['database_name'];

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating')");

        if ($result) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

But it's not working, I have error which is called "Oops! An error occurred." and I'm sure that database is ok, cause I'm using the same variable to read data from MySQL and it's fully working, so I think that there is something with PHP code.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query fails because you haven't closed it off properly. This is what you have:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating')");
```

<sup>*Notice the missing closing parenthesis (`)`) before you specify the `VALUES`*</sup>.

And this is what you need:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating) VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating')");
```

Comment: It works, I'll accept your answer in 7 minutes cause I can't do that now. Thanks

Comment: @LisSkis It's a pleasure. Just a note for future development - check your errors while developing to ensure you don't get silly errors like this ;-P. With `mysql_error()`/etc/etc. I'll also note as Script47 did in his answer, you should move away from `mysql_*` functions and into MySQLi/PDO :-)

Comment: I know, just sometimes you're looking on code and there is this one small thing, that you cannot see and you're getting mad :D

Comment: @Darren If the problem was caused by a typographical error, you should be voting to close them under the "typographical error" reason, not answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails because you haven't closed off the fields properly.

Change,

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating')");
```

To,

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $database_name . "(title, review, rating) VALUES('$title', '$review', '$rating')");
```

**Notice**

You should also consider switching from `mysql_*` to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) as `mysql` is [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated.

Finally, you are not sanitizing your user input which could allow people to use [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks to deface your site. Look in to [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Remember: [*Never trust user input.*](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don't_trust_user_input)

Comment: If the problem was caused by a typographical error, you should be voting to close them under the "typographical error" reason, not answer them.